# calculating the given limit

Tags: limits

Calculate the given lim:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}(1+xy)^{\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}}$$
My attemp is:
$1+xy= 1, where (x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$

and

$\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}\leq |x|$

Now for $x=r\cos\theta\rightarrow |x|=|r\cos\theta|\leq|r|$ I have:

$(1+xy)^{\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}}=1^{|r|}\rightarrow 1$, $r\rightarrow 0$

but i dint know it is correct. please help me

Comment: Can you show that $(\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert)^{-1} \leq \lvert x \rvert$? You might consider your limit along the two lines $(x, y) = (t, 0)$ as $t \to 0$ and $(x, y) = (t, t)$ as $t \to 0$, and see what you get.

Comment: can you tell me in more detail please

Comment: can you help me anyone

Comment: I suspect that this question will be closed in its current form. I suggest that you consider working through the two prompts in my comment and revising your question to include this additional work. When you revise your question, I also suggest that you correct the capitalization, spelling, and math-mode delimiters, as this sort of poor editing makes others feel like you aren't putting effort into either your question, or in the display of your question. For more, I suggest reading [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=(1+xy)^{\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}}$$
coordinate change:
$$(x,y)\Rightarrow(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$
now:
$$g(r,\theta)=(1+r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^{\frac{1}{r(|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|)}}$$
now maybe use the fact that:
$$1\le|\sin\theta|+|\cos\theta|\le\sqrt{2}$$
so we know that $g(r,\theta)$ is gonna be between:
$$(1+r^2\sin(2\theta)/2)^{\frac{1}{r}}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,(1+r^2\sin(2\theta)/2)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}r}}$$
if this limit converges we can use the fact that $\lim g^a=(\lim g)^a$ so lets just calculate:
$$g_1(r,\theta)=(1+r^2\sin(2\theta)/2)^{1/r}$$
since we also know that $-\frac12\le\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}\le\frac12$ and so lets say:
$$h(r,\theta)=(1+ar^2)^{1/r},\,\,|a|\le1/2$$
now you could instead say $u=\sqrt{a}r$ so:
$$L=(1+u^2)^{\sqrt{a}/u}$$
this should not be too hard